# External function with fullcalendar data

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using the following code to filter a fullcalendar inside eventRender(). But I would like to do the filtering from an external function but I cant access its data (info.event) . Is there a way a can import the data to then filter?

```
eventRender: function(info) {
var changeMatch = false;
var changeArr = [info.event.extendedProps.estado];
$('#calEstado option:selected').each(function(index, el){
if (changeArr.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0){changeMatch = true;}
});           
return (changeMatch);
}
```

The idea would be something like this..

```
$("#calendar_filter_form").submit(function() {

console.log("filter!");

//FILTER
var changeMatch = false;

var changeArr = [info.event.extendedProps.estado];

$('#calEstado option:selected').each(function(index, el){

if (changeArr.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0){changeMatch = true;}

});

return (changeMatch);

});
```

in version 3 I would do:

```
var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
alert("The view's title is " + view.title);
```

Comment: how about `eventRender: function(info) { return yourOtherFunction(info); }`? Have I missed the point?

Comment: it should be form submitted, I will edit the code..

Comment: this is fixed , as I set calendar to be global I moved the imported js files and now I can access it using `var view = calendar.view;

//var eventSources = calendar.getEventSources();
calendar.refetchEvents();`

Comment: thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is fixed , as I set calendar to be global I moved the imported js files and now I can access it using

```
var view = calendar.view;
var eventSources = calendar.getEventSources();
calendar.refetchEvents();
```